# Socket Error #113 No route to host on Android

Tags: android, delphi, indy, delphi-xe6, idhttp

In a Delphi XE6 FireMonkey app, when I press the button, I get the following error on Android:

> Socket Error #113 No route to host

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  datosPost: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  mRespuestaPost: String;
begin
  try
    datosPost := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    datosPost.AddFormField('usuario', txtUser.Text);
    datosPost.AddFormField('password', txtPass.Text);
    mRespuestaPost := DataModule2.IdHTTP.Post
      ('http://X.X.X.X/CGLB/ac.php', datosPost);
    ShowMessage(mRespuestaPost);
  finally
    datosPost.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Does the `TIdHTTP` component require another component to work?

Comment: What do you expect in mRepuestaPost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application failed to connect with `x.x.x.x`

To verify the error, try connecting to the host `x.x.x.x` from the same computer, using a web browser, or Telnet on port 80. If a normal web browser can not connect, Indy TIdHTTP will not be able too. (Ping is not useful for http)

Note: on Android, use the built-in default browser to do the test. Also check that the app permissions include the permission INTERNET.